# Why is Siri different on OSX Sierra vs iPhone

Tags: iphone, macos, siri

I have recently upgraded to Sierra and was looking forwards to Siri on the desktop, but to my surprise she is quite different than the phone version - she seems much less smart, often falling back to web searches for simple questions she could answer on the phone, and her voice is much less natural sounding. I would have expected her to be the same code calling the same backend servers - so what are the technical reasons for the differences, and why did Apple choose not to make them identical?

Comment: I'm not noticing any differences between my iPhone and Mac. I can't see Apple building-out an entirely different system on the backend for the two and haven't read/seen Apple indicate any differences.  Can you supply examples where you see differences existing?

Comment: "Tell me a joke" is consistently different between them

Comment: The jokes are different or the functionality is different?  I'm not near my Mac to check.

Comment: Phone Siri will tell me a joke, Mac Siri will say she doesn't understand or do a web search for it

Comment: When I ask Siri for a joke on my Mac, it works fine.  Make sure your OS is fully updated, there's nothing blocking Siri network access from your Mac, and try again.  Perhaps others here can try this and see if their results are similar.

Comment: It definitely needs some work. Siri on Mac won't display my weather unless I have WiFi turned on. It wants to triangulate my exact location based on nearby routers. As if my IP wasn't enough to go on, and weather will be different for me than my neighbor's router 100 feet away.

Comment: @Jules IP addresses are notoriously inaccurate for location detection. Even assuming that your provider has mapped your IP address to your city (which many don't bother to do), that doesn't mean it gets location within 100 feet of you. In a large city you could be tens of miles away from where a mapped IP puts you.

Comment: That's sort of part of my point... it's silly for desktop siri to require wifi to be turned on in order to tell me the weather. It's not GPS, and it's the same external IP as through ethernet.

Comment: Tell Siri on iPhone nowadays to translate anything into anything and she just does it! Yes, she actually says what you want in the language you want! On High Sierra however, this is not the case. She resorts to web search....